# Iframe in SAPUI5: After the first load URL is changed to parent page

Tags: javascript, xml, iframe, sapui5

I would like to embed an URL (https://www.google.com) with iframe into my SAPUI5 App. I'm using the following code in my xml view:

```
<core:HTML id="htmlExtern6" content="&lt;iframe src='/google/' width='100%' height='750px'&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;"/>
```

Here, '/google/' refers to a destination defined in SAP Cloud Platform to overcome the xframe='same-origin' problem. The URL https://www.google.com/ is used.

Destination in SCP:
[image: Destination in SCP]

When I open my APP and open the Tab with the `iframe` the google page is not completely loaded. I had the look in the chrome developer tools and there I could see that the URL is changed after the first load of the Page. So he tries to load the Google logo from the URL of my APP.

So the question is: Is there a way to prohibit the change of the URL so he uses the initial URL to load all components for the google? I have observed this behavior for several pages I try to embed.

Do I need some kind of JavaScript coding to keep this URL at its original state or reset ist after each load of a component?